# Admin account has it's own log in form and should not be able to log in in default log in form

Tags: 7, users

I have this certain problem which I don't know how to start doing this thing.

In drupal we have a log in form (let's call it **normal login form**) which **all** users can log in including admin.

So what I want is, to create a log in form for admin **only**. Which I already made it.

But the **problem** lies here, the normal login form should not let the admin proceed if the admin log in at the **normal log in form**

Here's a screenshot for it.

As you can see, that's the **normal log in form**. If the admin logged in to that, it should **not** let them proceed since **they have their own log in form**. All I want is only normal users can access can log in in this form.

[image]

Any possible solution for this?

Comment: Probably many, but why exactly you feel you need that separation? We don't want a solution to work around your true goal, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or hook_user_login() to check the roles of the user logging in and deny if the user is an administrator. Check the [Examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples) module for uses of hook_form_alter and other contrib modules like Legal and User Auth API are practical examples of extra validation and control during user authentication.